# Why doesn't my procedure return data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why doesn't the date range work?

It works when the input values are dates. When the input value is a date range then it doesn't return anything.

```
 Select CaseIncomingLetters.pk_CaseIncomingLetters_CaseIncomingLetterID, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterTo,
        CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterNo, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterFrom, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterEntryDateTime,
        Convert(varchar, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterDate, 106) as IncomingLetterDate, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterCopyTitle, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterCopy, 
        CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterComments, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterCC, CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterBody,
        CaseIncomingLetters.fk_WebUsers_CaseIncomingLetters_UserID, CaseIncomingLetters.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID,
        CaseIncomingLetters.fk_Cases_CaseIncomingLetters_CaseID, Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID, Cases.CaseNo, Cases.CaseTitle,
        ConcernedOffices.ConcernedOfficeName
 From CaseIncomingLetters
 Inner Join ConcernedOffices
 ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID= CaseIncomingLetters.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID
 Inner Join Cases
 ON Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID= CaseIncomingLetters.fk_Cases_CaseIncomingLetters_CaseID
 Inner Join Web_Users
 ON Web_Users.UserID= CaseIncomingLetters.fk_WebUsers_CaseIncomingLetters_UserID
 Inner Join Orgs
 ON Orgs.pk_Orgs_OrgID= Web_Users.fk_Orgs_OrgID_WebUsers
 Where Web_Users.fk_Orgs_OrgID_WebUsers= @TownID  AND Cases.CaseNo like '%'+ @CaseNo +'%' AND
 (CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterDate >= @DateFrom
 AND CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterDate < DATEADD(day, 1, @DateTo))
```

The input values are of DateTime type.

Update:

i tried this and it work but not above one

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [pk_CaseIncomingLetters_CaseIncomingLetterID]
      ,[fk_Cases_CaseIncomingLetters_CaseID]
      ,[IncomingLetterNo]
      ,[IncomingLetterComments]
      ,[IncomingLetterFrom]
      ,[IncomingLetterTo]
      ,[IncomingLetterBody]
      ,[IncomingLetterDate]
      ,[fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID]
      ,[IncomingLetterCC]
      ,[IncomingLetterCopy]
      ,[IncomingLetterCopyTitle]
      ,[IncomingLetterEntryDateTime]
      ,[fk_WebUsers_CaseIncomingLetters_UserID]
  FROM [LitMS_MCP].[dbo].[CaseIncomingLetters]
  Inner Join Web_Users
  ON Web_Users.UserID= CaseIncomingLetters.fk_WebUsers_CaseIncomingLetters_UserID
  Inner Join Orgs
  ON Orgs.pk_Orgs_OrgID= Web_Users.fk_Orgs_OrgID_WebUsers
  Inner Join Cases
  ON Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID= CaseIncomingLetters.fk_Cases_CaseIncomingLetters_CaseID
  Inner Join ConcernedOffices
  ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID= CaseIncomingLetters.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID
  Where  Web_Users.fk_Orgs_OrgID_WebUsers= 1  AND Cases.CaseNo like '%'+ '' +'%' 
  AND
  (CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterDate >= '1/Jan/1900'
  AND 
  CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterDate < DATEADD(day, 1, '21/Jan/2016'))
```

Comment: Your query returns no data for one of two reasons:  one or more tables are empty or the `where` and `on` clauses have no matches.  Those would be the typical reasons for such a result set.

Comment: Syntax look fine - either there is no data that matches those parameters or no data in the joined table(s) for those parameters.

Comment: Please add samples of data in your tables and desired output.

Comment: may be something to do with dateformatting; try CONVERT(VARCHAR, @yourdateVariable, 101)

Comment: just to check is IncomingLetterDate a datetime field in the database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff please check updated question

Comment: @DStanley please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubshooting steps I would take.

First comment out the date part of the where clause and possibly change the query temporarily to select top 10 (to reducthe amount of time teh query taks if this si a big dataset.

Now you can see the actual value of CaseIncomingLetters.IncomingLetterDate.

add in the first of the 2 date clauses in the where clause and change the variable to the actual date you found in one of the records originally returned. This makes sure you are looking for data in the variable is later tests that can actually be returned. If you get no results at this point, I have to wonder about datatypes in the table.

Now, change the value of the variable to be that variable and make the where clause use the variable. If it is populating the date in a  different format than the way it is stored in the database, likely you are looking at a collation issue.

Do the same with the second date clause.

The point where the records drop out is the point where you have the problem.

Comment: That's fine but BETWEEN is not equivalent to what you had earlier. Check to see which one is really, truly the data requirement.Between includes more records than what you had earlier as it is the equivalent of >= and <=. But your original was >= and <. Just getting data isn't enough, you have to be sure that you got the data the requirement specifies.

Comment: Could be your problem has has to do with the fact that you are ignoring the time component in the date. 2016-01-11 <> 2016-01-11 10:00:04.203 for instance